# Verdana font not working

Tags: fonts

I moved from one workstation to another (both are Win7) and made exactly the same installation from the same source files: MikTeX 2.9.4813 + TeXstudio 2.6.4.

When compiling the same input *.tex files on the new workstation, I am getting the following messages in the log file:

```
"pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file C:/Windows/Fonts/verdana.ttf): glyph `a' not found"
```

and so on for all the letters.

The resulting pdf shows empty square symbols instead of all letters.

I tried newer versions of MikTeX (2.9.6069) as well as TeXstudio (2.11.2), no change.

I am using:

```
\usepackage[nofligs]{verdana}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

If I comment out the first line, the result is fine, but not with the verdana font I would like.

How could I solve the problem?

---

@Ulrike Fischer: sorry for my late response.

1.I do not have the tex256.enc in my new latex installation.

2.If I put one in the same place as it was found on the old installation and do as you proposed, I get the default font in the resulting pdf, not verdana.

3.If I comment out the \fontfamily{verdana}\selectfont, I still get only squares.

4.Am I the first one to use verdana font on the "newer versions of the fonts in windows"? I would say no.

---

I found a working solution, thanks to Bernard's proposal: comment out the lines:

```
%\usepackage[nofligs]{verdana}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

add the lines:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Verdana}
```

and compile with XeLaTeX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you think of running `updmap.exe --verbose` from the command line (as admin)?

Comment: The glyph names seems to have changed in newer versions of the fonts in windows. You need either the older fonts or one would have to write new `.enc`-files which uses e.g. `/uni0041` instead of `/A` and adapt the map-files. No difficult but a lot of work.

Comment: @Bernard: I have run the command you propose. After lot of "Parsing", "Writing" and "Copying" the command reports, there is no change with the output pdf.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: 1) How can use the older fonts? I have already tried overwriting the C:/Windows/Fonts/verdanaX.ttf files with the ones form the older workstation. It didn't help. 2) Where can I find a more detailed explanation about how to write new .enc files and adapt the map files?

Comment: It would be simpler to compile with `xelatex`.

Comment: Try this. Create the directory [Your local texmf]/fonts/truetype/microsoft and copy the old microsoft fonts to this directory. You will have to rename the fonts according to the winfonts.map file that comes with winfonts package.  For example, the version of Arial bold was called Arial_bold.ttf while winfonts.map uses the name arialbd.ttf. Update the file name data base. It worked for me in texlive 2018. Hopefully, it will work in miktex also.

Answer (score 4):

Here a rough draft what you can try to repair the problem:

1. Find `tex256.enc`
2. Rename it as e.g. `winfonts256.enc`
3. Replace in this file `/T1Encoding [` with `/winfontsT1Encoding [`
4. Replace the glyph names by `uniXXXX` where XXXX is the Unicode number of the glyph, e.g. `/A` by `/uni0041` and `/a` by `/uni0061` (there are 256 glyphs, so it is some work involved.)

After some replacements you can test it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\pdfmapline{= rjvnr8t Verdana " winfontsT1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <winfonts256.enc <verdana.ttf}
\begin{document}

\fontfamily{verdana}\selectfont
AaTiäöpnß

\end{document}
```

I made two replacements and so get now this output:

[image]

You probably will have to do something similar for `ts1-winfonts.enc`. All the map entries that you will have to adapt can be found in `pdftex.map`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is `winfonts256.enc` I wrote according to @Ulrike Fischer's answer:

```
/winfontsT1Encoding [
/uni0060 %  grave
/uni00B4 %  acute
/uni005E %  circumflex
/uni007E %  tilde
/uni00A8 %  dieresis
/uni02DD %  hungarumlaut
/uni02DA %  ring
/uni02C7 %  caron
/uni02D8 %  breve
/uni00AF %  macron
/uni02D9 %  dotaccent
/uni00B8 %  cedilla
/uni02DB %  ogonek
/uni201A %  quotesinglbase
/uni2039 %  guilsinglleft
/uni203A %  guilsinglright

/uni201C %  quotedblleft
/uni201D %  quotedblright
/uni201E %  quotedblbase
/uni00AB %  guillemotleft
/uni00BB %  guillemotright
/uni2013 %  endash
/uni2014 %  emdash
/uniFEFF %  zerowidthnobreakspace
/uni2030 %  perthousand
/uni0131 %  dotlessi
/uni0237 %  dotlessj
/uniFB00 %  ff
/uniFB01 %  fi
/uniFB02 %  fl
/uniFB03 %  ffi
/uniFB04 %  ffl

/uni0020 % space
/uni0021 % exclam
/uni0022 % quotedbl
/uni0023 % numbersign
/uni0024 % dollar
/uni0025 % percent
/uni0026 % ampersand
/uni2019 % quoteright
/uni0028 % parenleft
/uni0029 % parenright
/uni002A % asterisk
/uni002B % plus
/uni002C % comma
/uni002D % hyphen
/uni002E % period
/uni002F % slash

/uni0030 % zero
/uni0031 % one
/uni0032 % two
/uni0033 % three
/uni0034 % four
/uni0035 % five
/uni0036 % six
/uni0037 % seven
/uni0038 % eight
/uni0039 % nine
/uni003A % colon
/uni003B % semicolon
/uni003C % less
/uni003D % equal
/uni003E % greater
/uni003F % question

/uni0040 % at
/uni0041 % A
/uni0042 % B
/uni0043 % C
/uni0044 % D
/uni0045 % E
/uni0046 % F
/uni0047 % G
/uni0048 % H
/uni0049 % I
/uni004A % J
/uni004B % K
/uni004C % L
/uni004D % M
/uni004E % N
/uni004F % O
/uni0050 % P
/uni0051 % Q
/uni0052 % R
/uni0053 % S
/uni0054 % T
/uni0055 % U
/uni0056 % V
/uni0057 % W
/uni0058 % X
/uni0059 % Y
/uni005A % Z
/uni005B % bracketleft
/uni005C % backslash
/uni005D % bracketright
/uni005E % asciicircum
/uni005F % underscore

/uni2018 % quoteleft
/uni0061 %  a
/uni0062 %  b
/uni0063 %  c
/uni0064 %  d
/uni0065 %  e
/uni0066 %  f
/uni0067 %  g
/uni0068 %  h
/uni0069 %  i
/uni006A %  j
/uni006B %  k
/uni006C %  l
/uni006D %  m
/uni006E %  n
/uni006F %  o

/uni0070 %  p
/uni0071 %  q
/uni0072 %  r
/uni0073 %  s
/uni0074 %  t
/uni0075 %  u
/uni0076 %  v
/uni0077 %  w
/uni0078 %  x
/uni0079 %  y
/uni007A %  z
/uni007B %  braceleft
/uni007C %  bar
/uni007D %  braceright
/uni007E %  asciitilde
/uni002D %  hyphen

/uni0102 %  Abreve
/uni0104 %  Aogonek
/uni0106 %  Cacute
/uni010C %  Ccaron
/uni010E %  Dcaron
/uni011A %  Ecaron
/uni0118 %  Eogonek
/uni011E %  Gbreve
/uni0139 %  Lacute
/uni013D %  Lcaron
/uni0141 %  Lslash
/uni0143 %  Nacute
/uni0147 %  Ncaron
/uni014A %  Eng
/uni0150 %  Ohungarumlaut
/uni0154 %  Racute

/uni0158 %  Rcaron
/uni015A %  Sacute
/uni0160 %  Scaron
/uni015E %  Scedilla % /Scommaaccent
/uni0164 %  Tcaron
/uni0162 %  Tcedilla % /Tcommaaccent
/uni0170 %  Uhungarumlaut
/uni016E %  Uring
/uni0178 %  Ydieresis
/uni0179 %  Zacute
/uni017D %  Zcaron
/uni017B %  Zdotaccent
/uni0132 %  IJ
/uni0130 %  Idotaccent
/uni0111 %  dcroat % /dbar % /dmacron
/uni00A7 %  section

/uni0103 %  abreve
/uni0105 %  aogonek
/uni0107 %  cacute
/uni010D %  ccaron
/uni010F %  dcaron % /dquoteright
/uni011B %  ecaron
/uni0119 %  eogonek
/uni011F %  gbreve
/uni013A %  lacute
/uni013E %  lcaron % /lquoteright
/uni0142 %  lslash
/uni0144 %  nacute
/uni0148 %  ncaron
/uni014B %  eng   % /ng
/uni0151 %  ohungarumlaut
/uni0155 %  racute

/uni0159 %  rcaron
/uni015B %  sacute
/uni0161 %  scaron
/uni015F %  scedilla % /scommaaccent
/uni0165 %  tcaron % /tquoteright
/uni0163 %  tcedilla % /tcommaaccent
/uni0171 %  uhungarumlaut
/uni016F %  uring
/uni00FF %  ydieresis
/uni017A %  zacute
/uni017E %  zcaron
/uni017C %  zdotaccent
/uni0133 %  ij
/uni00A1 %  exclamdown
/uni00BF %  questiondown
/uni00A3 %  sterling

/uni00C0 %  Agrave
/uni00C1 %  Aacute
/uni00C2 %  Acircumflex
/uni00C3 %  Atilde
/uni00C4 %  Adieresis
/uni00C5 %  Aring
/uni00C6 %  AE
/uni00C7 %  Ccedilla
/uni00C8 %  Egrave
/uni00C9 %  Eacute
/uni00CA %  Ecircumflex
/uni00CB %  Edieresis
/uni00CC %  Igrave
/uni00CD %  Iacute
/uni00CE %  Icircumflex
/uni00CF %  Idieresis

/uni00D0 %  Eth
/uni00D1 %  Ntilde
/uni00D2 %  Ograve
/uni00D3 %  Oacute
/uni00D4 %  Ocircumflex
/uni00D5 %  Otilde
/uni00D6 %  Odieresis
/uni0152 %  OE
/uni00D8 %  Oslash
/uni00D9 %  Ugrave
/uni00DA %  Uacute
/uni00DB %  Ucircumflex
/uni00DC %  Udieresis
/uni00DD %  Yacute
/uni00DE %  Thorn
/uni00DF %  SS

/uni00E0 %  agrave
/uni00E1 %  aacute
/uni00E2 %  acircumflex
/uni00E3 %  atilde
/uni00E4 %  adieresis
/uni00E5 %  aring
/uni00E6 %  ae
/uni00E7 %  ccedilla
/uni00E8 %  egrave
/uni00E9 %  eacute
/uni00EA %  ecircumflex
/uni00EB %  edieresis
/uni00EC %  igrave
/uni00ED %  iacute
/uni00EE %  icircumflex
/uni00EF %  idieresis

/uni00F0 %  eth
/uni00F1 %  ntilde
/uni00F2 %  ograve
/uni00F3 %  oacute
/uni00F4 %  ocircumflex
/uni00F5 %  otilde
/uni00F6 %  odieresis
/uni0153 %  oe
/uni00F8 %  oslash
/uni00F9 %  ugrave
/uni00FA %  uacute
/uni00FB %  ucircumflex
/uni00FC %  udieresis
/uni00FD %  yacute
/uni00FE %  thorn
/uni00DF %  germandbls
] def
```

First column is unicode, second column is PostScript name.
I looked up them from [Adobe Glyph List / aglfn13.txt](https://github.com/charlesmchen/typefacet/blob/master/data/Adobe%20Glyph%20List/aglfn13.txt)
I typed them by hand, I hope I didn't make mistakes.

I tested a few characters. It works well on my win11 computer with MiKTeX.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}%déjà chargé par luatextra
%\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX} % to have the automatics ligatures of TeX
\setromanfont{Verdana}

\begin{document}
\section{Example}
 This is a text in verdana

Math part is not in verdana
$x-3+2=8 $

\end{document}
```

Resulting in this:

[image]