# How can I use Verdana with pdflatex / TeXlive full 2017?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, ubuntu, texlive-2017

I thought simply including `\usepackage{verdana}` would be enough to use Verdana, but it seems like there is a problem:

I have a lot of fonts installed, as [`tlmgr list --only-installed | grep -i font` shows](https://gist.github.com/MartinThoma/67b67875acf038b1a01a4af30a02cb1c).

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I think I have texlive-full 2017 installed.

```
$ sudo tlmgr --version
tlmgr revision 45190 (2017-09-01 10:01:01 +0200)
tlmgr using installation: /usr/local/texlive/2017
TeX Live (http://tug.org/texlive) version 2017
```

Verdana is installed on my system (`sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts`):

```
$ locate -r "\\.ttf$"  | grep -i verdana
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Verdana.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Verdana_Bold.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Verdana_Bold_Italic.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Verdana_Italic.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/verdana.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/verdanab.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/verdanai.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/verdanaz.ttf
```

### Install winfonts

I've seen http://tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html and did the follwoing:

```
1. Download winfonts.zip from
https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/winfonts?lang=de

2. Extract the contents to 
$ sudo cp -r doc/ /usr/share/texmf/doc
$ sudo cp -r fonts/ /usr/share/texmf/fonts
$ sudo cp -r tex/ /usr/share/texmf/tex

3.
$ sudo texhash 

4.
$ cd winfonts/fonts/map/pdftex/winfonts
$ sudo updmap-sys --enable MixedMap winfonts.map
```

### Install verdana

The same steps for the verdana package:

```
1. Download  the zip file from
https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/verdana?lang=de

2. Copy the contents:
verdana.tds$ sudo cp -avr * /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/

3.
$ sudo texhash 

3.5
$ mktexlsr

4.
$ cd /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map/pdftex/ms/verdana
$ sudo updmap-sys --enable MixedMap verdana.map
```

### MWE 1

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verdana}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{document}
```

gives

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file vnamn8t): Font vnamn8t at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

### MWE 2

This runs just fine, but the result is not Verdana.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fontfamily{verdana}\selectfont
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{document}
```

Changing it to

```
\fontfamily{vna}\selectfont
```

doesn't change anything either. The text still has serifes and thus is not Verdana.

Comment: The package itself does not include the fonts.  I got it to work, by copying over the Windows Verdana fonts (from `C:\Windows\Fonts\Verdana`) into my `\localtexmf\fonts\truetype\Verdana` and recompiling with MWE #1.  Then it worked. (I use MikTeX)

Comment: The verdana package is not in texlive, only in miktex. You will have to install it manually from CTAN: https://ctan.org/pkg/verdana. You also will have to copy the fonts in a place where your texlive can find them. Be aware that there is a problem with the encoding file and the package currently doesn't work correctly in miktex (I don't know if it affects also verdana version in linux). https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339253/verdana-font-not-working.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I think I installed the verdana package. I've described the steps under "Install verdana". How can I verify I installed it / what did I do wrong?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes that looks rather dubious. But Martin wrote he has the fonts already so lets hope that he used a legal source ...

Comment: @Martin: You should better install the files not in texmf-dist but in your texmf-local. And check if verdana.sty is in tex/latex/. You second MWE doesn't work as you change the font in the preamble, and this is reset at \begin{document}.

Comment: I've installed it with `sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts`. @UlrikeFischer could you please tell me what I need to change to make the second one work? I tried all variants (before / after `\begin{document}`, with / without `\selectfont`, `\fontfamily{vna}` or `\fontfamily{verdana}`). None seemed to change anything.

Comment: If LaTeX can't find verdana.sty then it is quite probable that all other files of the package aren't found too. So don't try to change your code, find out why \usepackage{verdana} doesn't work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The package does not contain a `verdana.sty` file. Where should it come from?

Comment: There is a verdana.sty in the tds.zip: http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/fonts/verdana.tds.zip

Comment: Seems like this would be a good time to mention LuaLaTeX with fontenc, so that Verdana can be used directly, without any need for `\usepackage` as long as you have the actual font.

Comment: @RobtAll or XeLaTeX, for what it's worth.

Comment: Any news here? Does the answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to produce `verdana.sty` (along with `t1vna.fd`,`t1vnax.fd` and  `verdana.map` which are also not in the verdana.zip file) by running

```
tex verdana.ins
```

This ran docstrip on `verdana.dtx`.
Then I followed the instructions at http://tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html carefully, and finally got things working on Ubuntu 14.04 with texlive.
Running `tex testfont` and entering "vnamn8t" for *tfmname* let me see that most of the characters in the table were there.