# Report with Arial 11pt with line space 1.3 with minimal TeX installation

Tags: pdftex

I am new user in the TeX world. I have installed TeX with Debian as follows:

```
apt-get install --no-install-recommends texlive
```

It gives me a basic installation of about 200 Mb, with PDFLATEX.

The problem is that I need to have Arial 11 pt for a report. It must be Arial and not Helvetica. Since PDFLATEX does not allow to have TTF fonts, is there maybe a possible workaround or trick to allow PDFLATEX to produce (really) **Arial** 11pt.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\author{me}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\title{my report in arial 11pt}
\begin{document}
\section{my introduction}
Hello this is my report
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you really want to implement that guideline please also note that in TeX pt is different from pt in Word.

Comment: pdflatex can use ttf fonts. E.g. arial can (could) be used with the winfonts package (but not it longer works on my machine (windows 10) as the fonts has changed and the package was not adapted, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339269/2388). This can be repaired, but with lualatex or xelatex it is easier to use arial.

Comment: I managed to use Comic Sans MS (please, don't judge) in a document compiled with pdfLaTeX, but the solution works for one typeface only. i.e., to have a boldface you would have to replicate the procedure for the bold variant of the font. Would you like me to post that as an answer or is it useless to you?

Comment: Unfortunately  lualatex or xelatex  is not possible, as indicated above. May I add it in the first description (via edit)? As @Oleinik mentioned, it seems that there aren't any possbilities for PDFLatex. Hopefully genius idea will help us along in this question.

Comment: it seems that there aren't solutions, with using PDFLatex, right? What about importing possible fonts (old Adobe format)?