# Problem installing winfonts package in texlive 2018

Tags: installing, windows, truetype

I have problems installing winfonts package.  I am using Windows 10 and texlive 2018. I have carried out the instructions given in the package page for miktex,  adapted according to the page https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html for texlive.
When I try to compile the file below, pdf file is created, but I see only empty boxes. Curiously, the procedure worked flawlessly on Windows 7 machine with texlive 2018.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{winfonts}
\begin{document}
\fontfamily{georgia}\selectfont
abcdefg

\fontfamily{arial}\selectfont
abcdefg

\fontfamily{times-ttf}\selectfont
abcdefg

\fontfamily{verdana}\selectfont
abcdefg

\fontfamily{franklingothic}\selectfont
abcdefg

\fontfamily{impact}\selectfont
abcdefg
\end{document}
```

I am including the log file:

```
 ***********begin Log file*************************
    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.8.23)  23 AUG 2018 14:59
    entering extended mode
     restricted \write18 enabled.
     %&-line parsing enabled.
    **winfont-test.tex
    (./winfont-test.tex
    LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 2
    Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 27 language(s) loaded.
    (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
    Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
    (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
    File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    )
    \c@part=\count80
    \c@section=\count81
    \c@subsection=\count82
    \c@subsubsection=\count83
    \c@paragraph=\count84
    \c@subparagraph=\count85
    \c@figure=\count86
    \c@table=\count87
    \abovecaptionskip=\skip41
    \belowcaptionskip=\skip42
    \bibindent=\dimen102
    )
    (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
    Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package

    (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
    File: t1enc.def 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
    LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
    ))
    (c:/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/winfonts/winfonts.sty
    Package: winfonts 2006/01/13 v1.0 winfonts (Math Design Project)

    (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
    Package: textcomp 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package
    Package textcomp Info: Sub-encoding information:
    (textcomp)               5 = only ISO-Adobe without \textcurrency
    (textcomp)               4 = 5 + \texteuro
    (textcomp)               3 = 4 + \textohm
    (textcomp)               2 = 3 + \textestimated + \textcurrency
    (textcomp)               1 = TS1 - \textcircled - \t
    (textcomp)               0 = TS1 (full)
    (textcomp)             Font families with sub-encoding setting implement
    (textcomp)             only a restricted character set as indicated.
    (textcomp)             Family '?' is the default used for unknown fonts.
    (textcomp)             See the documentation for details.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting ? sub-encoding to TS1/1 on input line 79.

    (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def
    File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
    Now handling font encoding TS1 ...
    ... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding TS1

    (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.dfu
    File: ts1enc.dfu 2018/04/05 v1.2c UTF-8 support for inputenc
       defining Unicode char U+00A2 (decimal 162)
       defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
       defining Unicode char U+00A4 (decimal 164)
       defining Unicode char U+00A5 (decimal 165)
       defining Unicode char U+00A6 (decimal 166)
       defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
       defining Unicode char U+00A8 (decimal 168)
       defining Unicode char U+00A9 (decimal 169)
       defining Unicode char U+00AA (decimal 170)
       defining Unicode char U+00AC (decimal 172)
       defining Unicode char U+00AE (decimal 174)
       defining Unicode char U+00AF (decimal 175)
       defining Unicode char U+00B0 (decimal 176)
       defining Unicode char U+00B1 (decimal 177)
       defining Unicode char U+00B2 (decimal 178)
       defining Unicode char U+00B3 (decimal 179)
       defining Unicode char U+00B4 (decimal 180)
       defining Unicode char U+00B5 (decimal 181)
       defining Unicode char U+00B6 (decimal 182)
       defining Unicode char U+00B7 (decimal 183)
       defining Unicode char U+00B9 (decimal 185)
       defining Unicode char U+00BA (decimal 186)
       defining Unicode char U+00BC (decimal 188)
       defining Unicode char U+00BD (decimal 189)
       defining Unicode char U+00BE (decimal 190)
       defining Unicode char U+00D7 (decimal 215)
       defining Unicode char U+00F7 (decimal 247)
       defining Unicode char U+0192 (decimal 402)
       defining Unicode char U+02C7 (decimal 711)
       defining Unicode char U+02D8 (decimal 728)
       defining Unicode char U+02DD (decimal 733)
       defining Unicode char U+0E3F (decimal 3647)
       defining Unicode char U+2016 (decimal 8214)
       defining Unicode char U+2020 (decimal 8224)
       defining Unicode char U+2021 (decimal 8225)
       defining Unicode char U+2022 (decimal 8226)
       defining Unicode char U+2030 (decimal 8240)
       defining Unicode char U+2031 (decimal 8241)
       defining Unicode char U+203B (decimal 8251)
       defining Unicode char U+203D (decimal 8253)
       defining Unicode char U+2044 (decimal 8260)
       defining Unicode char U+204E (decimal 8270)
       defining Unicode char U+2052 (decimal 8274)
       defining Unicode char U+20A1 (decimal 8353)
       defining Unicode char U+20A4 (decimal 8356)
       defining Unicode char U+20A6 (decimal 8358)
       defining Unicode char U+20A9 (decimal 8361)
       defining Unicode char U+20AB (decimal 8363)
       defining Unicode char U+20AC (decimal 8364)
       defining Unicode char U+20B1 (decimal 8369)
       defining Unicode char U+2103 (decimal 8451)
       defining Unicode char U+2116 (decimal 8470)
       defining Unicode char U+2117 (decimal 8471)
       defining Unicode char U+211E (decimal 8478)
       defining Unicode char U+2120 (decimal 8480)
       defining Unicode char U+2122 (decimal 8482)
       defining Unicode char U+2126 (decimal 8486)
       defining Unicode char U+2127 (decimal 8487)
       defining Unicode char U+212E (decimal 8494)
       defining Unicode char U+2190 (decimal 8592)
       defining Unicode char U+2191 (decimal 8593)
       defining Unicode char U+2192 (decimal 8594)
       defining Unicode char U+2193 (decimal 8595)
       defining Unicode char U+2329 (decimal 9001)
       defining Unicode char U+232A (decimal 9002)
       defining Unicode char U+2422 (decimal 9250)
       defining Unicode char U+25E6 (decimal 9702)
       defining Unicode char U+25EF (decimal 9711)
       defining Unicode char U+266A (decimal 9834)
       defining Unicode char U+FEFF (decimal 65279)
    ))
    LaTeX Info: Redefining \oldstylenums on input line 334.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting cmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 349.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting cmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 350.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 351.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting cmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 352.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting cmbr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 353.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 354.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting ccr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 355.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting ptm sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 356.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting pcr sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 357.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting phv sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 358.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting ppl sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 359.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting pag sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 360.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting pbk sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 361.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting pnc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 362.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting pzc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 363.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting bch sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 364.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting put sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 365.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting uag sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 366.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting ugq sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 367.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting ul8 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 368.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting ul9 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 369.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting augie sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 370.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting dayrom sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 371.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting dayroms sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 372.

    Package textcomp Info: Setting pxr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 373.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting pxss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 374.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting pxtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 375.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting txr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 376.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting txss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 377.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting txtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 378.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting lmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 379.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting lmdh sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 380.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting lmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 381.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting lmssq sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 382.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting lmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 383.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting lmtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 384.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting qhv sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 385.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting qag sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 386.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting qbk sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 387.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting qcr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 388.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting qcs sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 389.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting qpl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 390.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting qtm sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 391.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting qzc sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 392.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting qhvc sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 393.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting futs sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 394.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting futx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 395.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting futj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 396.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting hlh sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 397.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting hls sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 398.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting hlst sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 399.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting hlct sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 400.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting hlx sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 401.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting hlce sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 402.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcn sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 403.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcw sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 404.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcf sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 405.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting pplx sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 406.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting pplj sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 407.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 408.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 409.
    )) (./winfont-test.aux)
    \openout1 = `winfont-test.aux'.

    LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
    LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
    LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
    LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
    LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
    LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
    LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
    LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
    LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
    LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
    LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
    LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
    LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
    LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for TS1+cmr on input line 4.

    (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
    File: ts1cmr.fd 2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
    )
    LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
    LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+georgia on input line 5
    .

    (c:/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/winfonts/t1georgia.fd
    File: t1georgia.fd 2006/01/21 Fontinst v1.926 font definitions for T1/georgia.
    )
    LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+arial on input line 8.

    (c:/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/winfonts/t1arial.fd
    File: t1arial.fd 2006/01/21 Fontinst v1.926 font definitions for T1/arial.
    )
    LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+times-ttf on input line
     11.

    (c:/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/winfonts/t1times-ttf.fd
    File: t1times-ttf.fd 2006/01/21 Fontinst v1.926 font definitions for T1/times-t
    tf.
    )
    LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+verdana on input line 1
    4.

    (c:/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/winfonts/t1verdana.fd
    File: t1verdana.fd 2006/01/21 Fontinst v1.926 font definitions for T1/verdana.
    )
    LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+franklingothic on input
     line 17.

    (c:/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/winfonts/t1franklingothic.fd
    File: t1franklingothic.fd 2006/01/21 Fontinst v1.926 font definitions for T1/fr
    anklingothic.
    )
    LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+impact on input line 20
    .

    (c:/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/winfonts/t1impact.fd
    File: t1impact.fd 2006/01/21 Fontinst v1.926 font definitions for T1/impact.
    ) [1

    {c:/texlive/2018/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./winfont-test
    .aux) ) 
    Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
     1062 strings out of 494041
     13659 string characters out of 6166738
     59090 words of memory out of 5000000
     4886 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
     18232 words of font info for 27 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
     286 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
     25i,4n,19p,163b,115s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
    {c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}{c:
    /texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/tex256.enc}<c:/Windows/Fonts/impa
    ct.ttf

    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/impact.ttf): glyph `a' not 
    found


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/impact.ttf): glyph `b' not 
    found


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/impact.ttf): glyph `c' not 
    found


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/impact.ttf): glyph `d' not 
    found


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/impact.ttf): glyph `e' not 
    found


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/impact.ttf): glyph `f' not 
    found


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/impact.ttf): glyph `g' not 
    found
    ><c:/Windows/Fonts/framd.ttf

    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/framd.ttf): glyph `a' not f
    ound


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/framd.ttf): glyph `b' not f
    ound


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/framd.ttf): glyph `c' not f
    ound


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/framd.ttf): glyph `d' not f
    ound


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/framd.ttf): glyph `e' not f
    ound


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/framd.ttf): glyph `f' not f
    ound


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/framd.ttf): glyph `g' not f
    ound
    ><c:/Windows/Fonts/verdana.ttf

    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/verdana.ttf): glyph `a' not
     found


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/verdana.ttf): glyph `b' not
     found


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/verdana.ttf): glyph `c' not
     found


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/verdana.ttf): glyph `d' not
     found


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/verdana.ttf): glyph `e' not
     found


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/verdana.ttf): glyph `f' not
     found


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/verdana.ttf): glyph `g' not
     found
    ><c:/Windows/Fonts/times.ttf

    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/times.ttf): glyph `a' not f
    ound


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/times.ttf): glyph `b' not f
    ound


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/times.ttf): glyph `c' not f
    ound


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/times.ttf): glyph `d' not f
    ound


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/times.ttf): glyph `e' not f
    ound


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/times.ttf): glyph `f' not f
    ound


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/times.ttf): glyph `g' not f
    ound
    ><c:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf

    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf): glyph `a' not f
    ound


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf): glyph `b' not f
    ound


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf): glyph `c' not f
    ound


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf): glyph `d' not f
    ound


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf): glyph `e' not f
    ound


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf): glyph `f' not f
    ound


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf): glyph `g' not f
    ound
    ><c:/Windows/Fonts/georgia.ttf

    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/georgia.ttf): glyph `a' not
     found


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/georgia.ttf): glyph `b' not
     found


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/georgia.ttf): glyph `c' not
     found


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/georgia.ttf): glyph `d' not
     found


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/georgia.ttf): glyph `e' not
     found


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/georgia.ttf): glyph `f' not
     found


    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/Fonts/georgia.ttf): glyph `g' not
     found
    ><c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1000.pfb>
    Output written on winfont-test.pdf (1 page, 41306 bytes).
    PDF statistics:
     37 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
     26 compressed objects within 1 object stream
     0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
     1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)

***************End of Log file******************
```

Comment: Formatting tip (at least works in the desktop version of Firefox): Mark text, press CTRL-k to have the text indented with four spaces (and thus have it formatted as source code)

Comment: The glyph names in the ttf have changed. So the mapping files of winfonts no longer work. See here for a draft how to correct this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339269/2388

Comment: Finally managed to get it working. Created  texmf-local/fonts/truetype/microsoft and copied the microsoft fonts installed by msttcorefonts package in linux to this folder, and renamed it according to winfonts.map. I then ran texhash as administrator. It works now.No need rename the fonts.

Comment: I meant renamed the fonts as in winfonts.map.

Comment: Yes, using the older fonts should work too.