# Does the comicsans package work on stock Windows 10?

Tags: fonts, windows, type1

I recently noticed that when using the `\usepackage{comicsans}` package in Windows 10, by default, all characters turn into squares. After a bit research, it was due to the fact that `COMIC.ttf` is no longer supported(included) in windows system????

A bit of shocking news. But then I manually downloaded and installed the font. However, when I use `\textbf{text}`, the characters wrapped inside still cannot be displayed correctly, as shown below.

Is there a way to solve it once for all?

Thanks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{comicsans}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[math]{iwona} %nice font
\usepackage[top=1cm,bottom=2cm,left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clears the header and footer
%\fancyhead[C]{\textbf{FE5116}}
\fancyfoot[L]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\textbf{Equation of a straight line}
\end{center}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\textwidth}

In mathematics we are almost obsessed with finding the equations of straight lines. There are different ways of doing this, but the best way is to use the equation:
\[
    y-y_1 = m(x-x_1),
\]
where $m$ is the gradient of the line and $(x_1,y_1)$ is the coordinates of a point on the line. \\

So, using this equation, find the equation of the following lines, giving your answer in the form
\[
    ax+by+c = 0,
\]
where $a,b,c$ are integers (whole numbers -- no fractions).
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
%
\end{minipage}



%% new command %%
\newcommand*{\myQues}[1]{%
\item #1 \\
    \vfill
    \hfill $\rule{6cm}{0.3mm}$ \quad (3)
}%

\begin{enumerate}[1)]
    \myQues{The line with gradient $4$ that passes through $(1,3)$.}
    \myQues{The line with gradient $2$ that passes through $(6,2)$.}
    \cleardoublepage
    \myQues{The line with gradient $1$ that passes through $(2,-3)$.}
    \myQues{The line with gradient $10$ that passes through $(-4,-6)$.}
    \cleardoublepage
    \myQues{The line with gradient $-2$ that passes through $(4,1)$.}
    \myQues{The line with gradient $-3$ that passes through $(-2,-5)$.}
\end{enumerate}

%\end{document}


\cleardoublepage
Now, what happens if the gradient is a fraction? We still want our final answer to consist of integers -- so no fractions \ldots

\begin{enumerate}[1)]
\setcounter{enumi}{6}
\myQues{The line with gradient $\frac{1}{2}$ that passes through $(5,2)$.}
\myQues{The line with gradient $\frac{2}{3}$ that passes through $(6,1)$.}
\cleardoublepage
\myQues{The line with gradient $\frac{3}{4}$ that passes through $(2,-2)$.}
\myQues{The line with gradient $-\frac{1}{5}$ that passes through $(-2,4)$.}
\cleardoublepage
\myQues{The line with gradient $3$ that passes through $(\frac{1}{3},4)$.}
\myQues{The line with gradient $-2$ that passes through $(-\frac{1}{4},-\frac{2}{9})$.}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you also install Comic Sans Bold?

Comment: @Davislor No, I did not. Honestly I did not expect such a problem (from MS). I don't see any point of removing a font and WHY? It's also not easy to find/download from the internet. I spend 10 minutes looking for it. What's the file name for the `Bold` font? Or do you know a place I can download them from? Thanks.

Comment: The list of filenames is [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/fonts/windows_10_font_list). It should be included with Windows 10. Try loading it with `fontspec`.

Comment: On an OS other than Windows or OS X, or if for some reason they’re missing (check with `fc-list`), you can download an older version using [MS Core Fonts for the Web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_fonts_for_the_Web).

Comment: @Davislor Weirdly, I don't think they are! It's not the first time I realised it. I had problems in both Win10 1083 and 1809 versions.

Comment: @Davislor Now I can confirm that I have the `comicbd.ttf`, but the characters are still squares ...

Comment: First, try running `updmap-sys`, `mktexlsr` and `fc-cache` (if using TeX Live). Also delete your `.aux` files. Then try again.

Comment: @Davislor Tried all. Not sure if this is a font issue any more. See updated screenshot from Adobe on font information for the PDF file, if that gives any clue?

Comment: Since you’re using Type 1 versions of the font on PDFLaTeX, you need to regenerate the `.pfb` files according to the instructions in the package manual now that the fonts are installed.

Comment: @Davislor hmmmm, never had any problem when using Windows 7. Thanks. Will explore more now.

Comment: However, all of this will be simpler and work better (like support for Greek and italics and foreign languages and OpenType features) if you just switch to the modern toolchain with `fontspec`.

Comment: The `comicsans` CTAN package does not include Type 1 versions of the font, for legal reasons, You need to install the `TTF` files, then generate the Type 1 font yourself. Since you didn’t have the bold font installed when you did it the first time, you need to do it a second time.

Comment: @Davislor Comic sans MS was a "commercial" Microsoft font included with purchased products e.g. Office thus not included in native windows 10

Comment: @KJO I had MS Office 2019 installed on the system, but didn't seem to have `COMIC.ttf`. Is that normal?

Comment: @CasperYC I’m seeing contradictory information: the font *is* on [the Windows 10 font list,](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/fonts/windows_10_font_list) but Windows 10 is *not* [on the list of products that ship with the font on this page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/comic-sans-ms)

Comment: @CasperYC I have the font on my Windows 10 machine, but I upgraded from Windows 7, which is on the list, so it might have come from there, or from my copy of Office.

Comment: Ah, I think I found the explanation.

Comment: Are you sure the fonts weren’t just deleted? In your browser history, did anyone visit Ban Comic Sans? ;)

Comment: The package needs an update. It no longer works with current version of comic.ttf - the names in the encoding file are wrong (similar things happened e.g. with the winfonts package), see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339269/2388

Comment: @Davislor For your information, I installed Win 10 1083 and 1089 version from a clean slate, together with MSO 2019. None of the combinations had/supported `comic.ttf` and displayed the characters as squares.

Comment: @CasperYC You say "I did not expect such a problem (from MS)".  Why not, it comes provided with many problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to UlrikeFischer, I’ve removed an inaccurate paragraph here.  The package is out-of-date and incompatible with recent versions of Comic Sans MS.

You can try replacing the `comicsans` package with `fontspec`:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchUppercase}
\setmainfont{Comic Sans MS}[Scale = 1.0]
```

If you also want to replace the math letters, you might load `mathastext` afterwards, or

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[range = up]{Comic Sans MS}
\setmathfont[range = it]{Comic Sans MS Italic}
\setmathfont[range = bfup]{Comic Sans MS Bold}
\setmathfont[range = bfit]{Comic Sans MS Bold Italic}
```

According to Microsoft, Comic Sans MS [is in fact included with Windows 10](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/fonts/windows_10_font_list).

You can legally obtain the older version of that’s compatible with `comicsans` *gratis* as part of the redistributable Microsoft Core Fonts for the Web.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with `pdflatex`? I don't think `pdflatex` work with `fontspec`.

Comment: Btw, before I downloaded `comic.ttf`, the PDF was displayed as squares only. And when I was installing the file for the very first time, windows did not show any warning of replacing an existing font. So it must be a BUG for Windows 10.

Comment: If you’re using PDFLaTeX, you will need to regenerate Type 1 versions of the fonts according to the instructions in [the package manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/comicsans). Repeat them now that your bold font is installed.

Comment: The comicsans package uses the ttf-font directly. A conversion to type1 is only needed for the optional italic and cyrilic variants. But the encoding files of comicsans seems not be compatible with the ttf anymore - probably the font changed. One should inform the author of the package, he needs to adapt it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah. The font has indeed changed over the years.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've removed the inaccurate information. Thank you!