# Comic Sans in Windows MiKTeX

Tags: fonts, miktex

All I have done is write a code like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comicsans}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    Hello World!
\end{document}
```

The output consists of empty black-bordered rectangles with the dimension of the letters. I do not know how to fix it. I have already installed the `comicsans` package form MiKTeX console.

Comment: Is the font mentioned in `updmap.cfg`?

Answer (score 2):

In XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you can use the TrueType font directly:

```
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \setmainfont{Comic Sans}
```

If you also want to use it for math (and it has a surprisingly large repertoire of math symbols), you can use `mathastext`, `unicode-math` or `mathspec`.

Comment: I have tried using your solution, but numbers inside math mode do not appear in ComicSans, they are printed in Computer Modern. The rest works perfectly. How can I fix that?

Comment: @user258200 Did you `\usepackage{mathastext}`?

Comment: Yes, I did @Davislor

Answer (score 2):

The package comicsans is rather old and it not longer works with the version of the font provided by a current windows.

The situation is quite similar to verdana and the other winfonts (see [Verdana font not working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339253/2388)).

To get it working again you would have to create a new encoding file or get the author to do it along the lines in my answer to the other question https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339269/2388

The alternative is to use xelatex or lualatex as suggested by Davislor.